# database-adminstration tag should be synonym of database-administration, not other way round

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

`database-administration` is currently a synonym of `database-adminstration`:
https://serverfault.com/tags/database-adminstration/synonyms

It should be the other way round.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't we actually fix the problem and do a mass retag of that incorrect spelling, rather than apply a plaster like this?

I'm not suggesting the muggles among us do it (there are 157 tagged questions), but if a moderator or developer can do a mass retag without spamming the front page I think that would be far more preferable than allowing this misspelling to continue to exist.

Comment: you're right. I've "merged" the tags which is a de facto mass re-tag.

Answer (score 3):

Good point.

Fixed. Good thing that's a one-click fix.